# The probability of failure in drawn number n+1 given that we already fialed in drawn number n

Tags: probability

Two boxes are U and V. Box U contains 6 white balls and 4 black balls.  Box V contains 3 white balls and 7 black balls.

We consider the following game: a person randomly chooses one of the two boxes;  A ball is drawn at random.  If it was white, he won, and if it was black, he lost; In this case, he chooses a second time at random in one of the two boxes and draws a ball there and so on without replacing the ball after any draw. Then he continues until he wins. For n of IN, let Bn and Mn be the two events: Bn: "The person wins on trial number n."  Mn: "Person loses at trial number n"

In other words, the event Bn means that the person draws a white ball in the draw number n. We start counting from 1.

So for instance the event B1 means that the player chose one of the two boxes with equal probability. Then he draws a white ball from U with the probability 6/10, or he draws a white ball a white ball from V with the probability 3/10. Thus: `P(B1) = 1/2*6/10 + 1/2*x3/10`

To understand this game I used this picture:

[this is a link for the graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo1FB.png)

Now Remarque that the intersection of B1 and M1 is the empty set (impossible event), B1 and M1 union is the absolute event (its probability is one) are a repartition of the universe of possibilities.
This will help us calculate P(M2):

`P(M2) = P(M1)*P(M2/M1) + P(B1)*P(M2/B1)`

Calculate the probability of events: B1, B2/B1, M2/B1, B2, M2, Mn+1/Mn.

> What I do care about is the probability of Mn+1/Mn. I wonder if there's a way to come up with a formula or a relation that links the failure in drawn number n and its following drawn.

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Are the balls replaced after being drawn?  Does the player get to keep track of the results or is the game re-randomized each round?  Also, please edit to include your efforts.  Surely you have computed some of the desired quantities.

Comment: Yes Indeed, I calculated some of the desired quantities, and thank you for highlighting the ambiguities, I will clarify more:)

Comment: Should say, it's also not clear what $M_n$ is.  Is $M_n$ the same as "the probability that black is drawn at least $n$ times"?

Comment: Post edit:  given that the contents of the boxes change over time, and the player keeps the history, there is a strategy here.  Should the player stick with a given box or switch?  It's not obvious and, of course, the chosen strategy changes the probability.  Nor is it obvious what the player is trying to optimize...that will need to be specified before you can ask for the optimal strategy.

Comment: The choice of the box is random. You can't decide a prior which box to pick fron.

Comment: As I say, the rules are not clear.  All of this should be spelled out explicitly in your post.

Comment: the problem, of course, is that the game is path dependent.  That is to say, it makes a big difference if you have depleted the black balls from one box or if you have drawn from each evenly. Easy enough to program, just create states for the possible contents of the boxes.

Comment: If you just want an answer for this exact question, the easiest way to get it is to program a quick search. It has to end in 12 turns, so the search will be quick. If you want to solve it analytically, you need to look at more than just $B_n, M_n$. You should at least include $U_n = $ the number of times $U$ was picked in the first $n$ trials. With that added information you can develop recursive formulas for all three.